# grab value between two strings with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have the following data on one line:

```
<a href="#page-metadata-start" class="assistive">Go to start of metadata</a>
<div id="page-metadata-end" class="assistive"></div>

        <fieldset class="hidden parameters">
                        <input type="hidden" title="browsePageTreeMode" value="view">
        </fieldset>

        <div class="wiki-content">
           <p>(openissues)81(/openissues)</p><p>(assignstoday)0(/assignstoday)</p><p>(assignsweek)2(/assignsweek)</p><p>(replyissues)6(/replyissues)</p><p>(wrapissues)26(/wrapissues)</p>
        </div>
```

I'd like to grab the value for "openissues" for example, but I can't figure out to properly retrieve this. One of the things I tried is the following command:

```
sed -n '/(assignstoday)/,/(\/assignstoday)/p' ~/test.txt
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*(openissues)\(.*\)(\/openissues).*/\1/' test.txt
```

a quick hack to possibly meet your edited requirement:

```
sed -n '/openissues/p' test.txt | sed  's/.*(openissues)\(.*\)(\/openissues).*/\1/'
```

but regexes are really not the way to go when parsing HTML.

Comment: Hi Neil, when I use this it outputs all the original content instead of just the value, how come?

Comment: Works for me on the sample input you provided. Perhaps you have a typo - did you copy and paste it?

Comment: Sorry Neil, my fault. I expanded my example to show the behavior. Can you please take a look? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try

```
VALUE=openissues
sed  's@.*('"$VALUE"')\([^(]\+\).*@\1@'
```

that is, replace everything except the contents of what you are searching, with that content.

edit: Now I see Neil's answer, that's practically the same, accept his. I leave my answer for the customization of which value you want to extract.